jQuery UI resizable - scroll container
I'm trying to use jQuery UI resizable to resize an element that's within a scrollable container and want the container to scroll automatically as I drag the element near to the bottom edge of the container.
My code's below.  I am using the resize event to scroll the container and adjust the element height to compensate for the scroll. But it doesn't work - the element is not resized as much as it should be.  What am I missing?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<style>
#outer {
  height: 30em;
  width: 20em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
}
#middle {
  height: 60em;
  width: 15em;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
#inner {
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  outline: 10px solid lightblue;
  outline-offset: -11px;
}
.helper {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

$( function() {
  let resize = function (event, ui) {
    // If we're nearing the bottom, scroll down
    let outer = $('#outer');
    let gap = outer.outerHeight() - event.pageY;
    if (gap < 30) {
      let delta = Math.max(0, gap);
      outer[0].scrollBy({top: delta, left:0, behavior: 'instant'});
      ui.size.height += delta;
    };
  };
  $( "#inner" ).resizable({
    helper: "helper",
    resize: resize
  });
} );
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="middle">
      <div id="inner">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>


I discovered, by looking at the source of jQuery UI, that after scrolling, some of the internal properties of the resizable instance need to be updated.  The solution is therefore to extend ui.resizable, thus getting access to the internals:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<style>
#outer {
  height: 30em;
  width: 20em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
}
#middle {
  height: 60em;
  width: 15em;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
#inner {
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  outline: 10px solid lightblue;
  outline-offset: -11px;
}
.helper {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$.widget('ui.resizable', $.ui.resizable, {
    options: {
      scrollableContainer: null
    },
    _mouseDrag: function(event) {
        if (this.options.scrollableContainer)
        {
          const container = this.options.scrollableContainer;
          const gap = container.position().top + container.outerHeight() - event.pageY;
          if (gap < 30) {
            let delta = Math.max(0, gap);
            if (delta) {
              container[0].scrollBy({top: delta, left:0, behavior: 'instant'});
              this.originalMousePosition.top -= delta;
              this.originalPosition.top -= delta;
              this.position.top -= delta;
              this.prevPosition.top -= delta;
              this.helper.css({
                top: (this.helper.offset().top - delta) + 'px',
                left: (this.helper.offset().left) + 'px'
              });
            }
          };   
        }
 
        // Invoke the parent widget's _mouseDrag().
        return this._super(event);
    }
});

$( function() {
  $( "#inner" ).resizable({
    helper: "helper",
    scrollableContainer: $('#outer')
  });
} );
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="middle">
      <div id="inner">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

